# Disable specific WIN shortcuts without additional software (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, shortcuts, virtual-desktop

**I would like to know hot to disable specific <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + shortcuts (Windows 10) without any third party software (with only included Windows 10 tools).**

Particularly <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> one (*create new virtual desktop*).

[This](https://winaero.com/disable-certain-winkey-shortcuts-in-windows-10/) article shows a way how to disable simple shortcuts like <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Its about creating registry string value **"DisabledHotkeys"** at *`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`*. It works, but no any mention on how to represent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key or any other service keys. Does anyone know what should I type to match correct <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut in there?